# Reading and writing to a JSON file in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write a JSON file depending on the user-input, I am successfully being able to write to my file if my entry is new, however part of what I am trying to achieve is to see if a certain data is already present in the JSON file for ex here I already have "Raj is travelling to London" with an intent "greet", therefore I do not need to append a new entry, what I want here would be to check if the text already exists and then to change it or leave it unchanged based on the user input.

Please ask if any clarifications are needed.

However I am unable to accomplish this, could anyone tell me what is wrong with my code.

```
from rasa_nlu.model import Metadata, Interpreter
from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUConfig
import logging
from pprint import pprint
import json
from rasa_nlu.converters import load_data
from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer


result_dict = {}
change_dict = {}

# Open the training file
input_training_file = '/home/{user.name}/AIData/demo-rasa.json'

with open(input_training_file) as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)

outfile = open(input_training_file, 'w')


example_data = [[data['rasa_nlu_data']['common_examples'][i]['text'], data['rasa_nlu_data']['common_examples'][i]['intent']]
                 for i in range(0, len(data['rasa_nlu_data']['common_examples']))]

def retrain_model(input_file):
    training_data = load_data(input_file)
    trainer = Trainer(RasaNLUConfig('config_spacy.json'))
    trainer.train(training_data)
    model_directory = trainer.persist('/home/{user.name}/AIData/models/', model_name='my_model')


model_directory = '/home/{user.name}/AIData/models/my_model'
metadata = Metadata.load(model_directory)
interpreter = Interpreter.load(metadata, RasaNLUConfig('config_spacy.json'))

# Parsing the text
user_text = u"Raj is travelling to London"
result_dict = interpreter.parse(user_text)

outfile = open(input_training_file, 'w')

intent = result_dict['intent']['name']
print "Intent: " + intent

print "Is " + intent + " the correct intent? "

response = raw_input("Yes or No ").lower()

if response == 'yes':
    outfile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
elif response == 'no':
    change_dict['text'] = user_text
    print change_dict['text']
    for text_examples in example_data:
        print text_examples
        if change_dict['text'].lower() in map(lambda x: x.lower(), text_examples):
            print "Text already exists with the intent " + text_examples[1]
            change_input = raw_input("Do you want to change the intent?")
            if change_input.lower() == 'yes':
                training_response = raw_input("What should be the intent?")
                # change_dict['intent'] = training_response.lower()
                data['rasa_nlu_data']['common_examples'][text_examples]['intent'] = training_response.lower()
                outfile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4) + '\n')
                outfile.close()
            elif change_input.lower() == 'no':
                pass
            else:
                print "Please enter yes or no"
        else:
            training_response = raw_input("What should be the intent? ")
            change_dict['intent'] = training_response
            change_dict['entities'] = []
            data['rasa_nlu_data']['common_examples'].append(change_dict)
            outfile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4) + '\n')
            outfile.close()
            retrain_model(input_training_file)
            break
else:
    print "Please enter 'Yes' or 'No' "
```

Here is the sample JSON file which I am trying to write to:

```
{
    "rasa_nlu_data": {
        "common_examples": [
            {
                "text": "hey", 
                "intent": "greet", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "howdy", 
                "intent": "greet", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "hey there", 
                "intent": "greet", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "hello", 
                "intent": "greet", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "hi", 
                "intent": "greet", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "good morning", 
                "intent": "greet", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "good evening", 
                "intent": "greet", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "dear sir", 
                "intent": "greet", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "yes", 
                "intent": "affirm", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "yep", 
                "intent": "affirm", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "yeah", 
                "intent": "affirm", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "indeed", 
                "intent": "affirm", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "that's right", 
                "intent": "affirm", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "ok", 
                "intent": "affirm", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "great", 
                "intent": "affirm", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "right, thank you", 
                "intent": "affirm", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "correct", 
                "intent": "affirm", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "great choice", 
                "intent": "affirm", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "sounds really good", 
                "intent": "affirm", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "i'm looking for a place to eat", 
                "intent": "restaurant_search", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "I want to grab lunch", 
                "intent": "restaurant_search", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "I am searching for a dinner spot", 
                "intent": "restaurant_search", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "i'm looking for a place in the north of town", 
                "intent": "restaurant_search", 
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "start": 31, 
                        "end": 36, 
                        "value": "north", 
                        "entity": "location"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "text": "show me chinese restaurants", 
                "intent": "restaurant_search", 
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "start": 8, 
                        "end": 15, 
                        "value": "chinese", 
                        "entity": "cuisine"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "text": "show me chines restaurants", 
                "intent": "restaurant_search", 
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "start": 8, 
                        "end": 14, 
                        "value": "chinese", 
                        "entity": "cuisine"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "text": "show me a mexican place in the centre", 
                "intent": "restaurant_search", 
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "start": 31, 
                        "end": 37, 
                        "value": "centre", 
                        "entity": "location"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "start": 10, 
                        "end": 17, 
                        "value": "mexican", 
                        "entity": "cuisine"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "text": "i am looking for an indian spot called olaolaolaolaolaola", 
                "intent": "restaurant_search", 
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "start": 20, 
                        "end": 26, 
                        "value": "indian", 
                        "entity": "cuisine"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "text": "search for restaurants", 
                "intent": "restaurant_search", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "anywhere in the west", 
                "intent": "restaurant_search", 
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "start": 16, 
                        "end": 20, 
                        "value": "west", 
                        "entity": "location"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "text": "anywhere near 18328", 
                "intent": "restaurant_search", 
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "start": 14, 
                        "end": 19, 
                        "value": "18328", 
                        "entity": "location"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "text": "I am looking for asian fusion food", 
                "intent": "restaurant_search", 
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "start": 17, 
                        "end": 29, 
                        "value": "asian fusion", 
                        "entity": "cuisine"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "text": "I am looking a restaurant in 29432", 
                "intent": "restaurant_search", 
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "start": 29, 
                        "end": 34, 
                        "value": "29432", 
                        "entity": "location"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "text": "I am looking for mexican indian fusion", 
                "intent": "restaurant_search", 
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "start": 17, 
                        "end": 38, 
                        "value": "mexican indian fusion", 
                        "entity": "cuisine"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "text": "central indian restaurant", 
                "intent": "restaurant_search", 
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "start": 0, 
                        "end": 7, 
                        "value": "central", 
                        "entity": "location"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "start": 8, 
                        "end": 14, 
                        "value": "indian", 
                        "entity": "cuisine"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "text": "bye", 
                "intent": "goodbye", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "goodbye", 
                "intent": "goodbye", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "good bye", 
                "intent": "goodbye", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "stop", 
                "intent": "goodbye", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "end", 
                "intent": "goodbye", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "farewell", 
                "intent": "goodbye", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "Bye bye", 
                "intent": "goodbye", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "have a good one", 
                "intent": "goodbye", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "Raj is travelling to London", 
                "intent": "goodbye", 
                "entities": []
            }, 
            {
                "text": "Raj is travelling to London", 
                "intent": "goodbye", 
                "entities": []
            }
        ], 
        "entity_synonyms": [
            {
                "synonyms": [
                    "Chinese", 
                    "Chines", 
                    "chines"
                ], 
                "value": "chinese"
            }
        ], 
        "regex_features": [
            {
                "pattern": "[0-9]{5}", 
                "name": "zipcode"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: *“see if a certain data is already present in the JSON file”* – You have the wrong mindset here: The JSON file is just a serialized form of a data structure in Python. You can only read the file completely, or write it completely. So all your logic should operate on the data *only*. There should be no mixed JSON reading or writing in there. You read the data from the file, execute your logic, and then at the end write it back. Once you have it like that, your logic should become a lot more clear and easier to understand.

Comment: Yes I read the complete json file, and write it accordingly, the problem arises if I run my code again with the same text again, it writes it to my file instead of checking that the text already has been written to the file before, hope you understand